# android how to set hidden keyboard for an edittext

Tags: android, datepicker

In my app i have an editText . If i click on that then it should open the date picker dialog not the keyboard.
Its opening date piker but along with keyboard also coming.

(by default keyboard come for editText but i dont want that)
I want for this editText keyboard should not visible/ should be hidden.

How can i do that?

I did like this,

```
   private EditText editDate;
  editDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDate);

editDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editDate.getWindowToken(), 0);

                 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
```

its not working. Is there any way?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: +1, working fine ! but when I click on x button keyboard popups!

Answer (score 2):

This thing is working. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/sheduleDatePicker1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

you might have to make it visible again when your date picker resigns, so that your other edit text should receive keyboard..

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: within editText click event i ll give the 1st line. and where i ll put the 2nd line?

Comment: no, its not working. i tried but still keyboard is coming first then date picker

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) thread and [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7115) issue..

Answer (score 0):

In the ActivityLayout xml file change editDate to uneditable. For example, i used this in my xml:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/date_EditText"
        android:editable="false"  <---- this is what you want
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="none" 
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```